FastAPI no module named "my module" - FastAPI cannot find my Python Package
FastAPI cannot find my Python Package. It seems relatively obvious that this is an issue with Python paths and imports, however I do not know how to fix it.
What surprised me is that this worked when using Flask instead of FastAPI. I converted a small application from Flask to FastAPI, and this is when the import statements no longer were able to find my Python package.
I don't know enough about the FastAPI-cli to understand what it does / does not do with paths to know how to fix it.
Here's a very simple MWE.
# /fastapi/fastapi_mwe.py

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

from my_package import my_value

print(f'__name__={__name__}')
app = FastAPI()

class FastAPI_Value(BaseModel):
    value: int

@app.get('/')
def root(fastapi_value: FastAPI_Value):
    next_value = fastapi_value.value + my_value
    return {
        'next_value': next_value
    }

# /my_package/__init__.py

my_value = 1

Here's the project structure:
stack_overflow_mwe/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
    fastapi/
        fastapi_mwe.py

Here's how I run fastapi_mwe.py:
user@host:/home/user/stackoverflow_mwe/$ fastapi dev fastapi/fastapi_mwe.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `my_package`

How should I structure this project and how can I fix this? I don't really want to put the package my_package into the subdirectory fastapi, because this package should be totally independent of the fastapi wrapper/webserver. I should be able to create a new subfolder called flask_api and be able to import my_package from both locations.
I have also tried to avoid using .venv and an editable install + pyproject.toml. I am using virtual environments to manage dependencies (for example I did pip3 install fastapi to install the fastapi package into a local .venv). If there is no alternative, then I can create a pyproject.toml and setup the local packages as an editable install, but I don't really want to do this unless there is no alternative.

Edit: PYTHONPATH
I tried to print the value of PYTHONPATH and found that it does not exist. (When running with fastapi.)
import os

print(f'__name__={__name__}')
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])

This seems strange, but suggests that whatever the CLI fastapi does, it doesn't set the PYTHONPATH variable to the cwd.
Any thoughts?

sys.path.append("/home/user/stackoverflow_mwe")  before you import your module.

to make sure: it has to be /home/user/stackoverflow_mwe, not /home/user/stackoverflow_mwe/my_package

shorter: print(f'{__name__=}'). OR with spaces print(f'{__name__ = }')

problem depends on where Python runs code - it depends on what is Current Working Directory which you can check with print( os.getcwd() ), Maybe Flask was using home/user/stackoverflow_mwe as CWD but fastapi can use other folder as CWD - and  this can make difference.

BTW: if you would add sys.path.insert(0, "/home/user/stackoverflow_mwe") before from fastapi import FastAPI then sometimes it could try to load your folder fastapi instead of module fastapi and this could makes problem.

in your situation can work also sys.path.append('.') - if you will always run it in folder /home/user/stackoverflow_mwe

Do you happen to know what fastapi does with paths? Normally you would expect something like this to work. For example, if the contents of the fastapi directory were just a regular Python package, then you would expect my_package to be on the path if you run python3 fastapi.py. But in this case, running with fastapi (the binary/executable cli) seems to remove something from the Python path, or otherwise over-write it.

when I check sys,path directly in python then first element is empty string "" which probably means current folder but if I do it in fastapi code then there is no "" in sys.path. Probably command fastapi changes settings. Maybe for security reason - so it can't use unknown modules if you run it different folder(s)

You run it in /home/user/stackoverflow_mwe and os.getcwd() added to code shows me that fastapi really uses this folder as Current Working Directory so it should work.
Normally sys.path shows me empty string "" as first element which probably means current folder - and when I run flaskapi then it doesn't have it.
It seems flaskapi removes current folder from sys.path (maybe for security reason - so it can't run unknown modules in other folders) and it may need to add sys.path.append('') (or sys.path.append('.')) before import to work again.
But if you plan to run it from different folder (or to make sure it will work if you accidentally run from other folder) you could add full path /home/user/stackoverflow_mwe
#print( os.getcwd() )

import sys

#sys.path.append('.')
sys.path.append('/home/user/stackoverflow_mwe')

from my_package import my_value


To make sure: it has to be /home/user/stackoverflow_mwe,
not /home/user/stackoverflow_mwe/my_package
